# A website converted to android app using webview - Is it categoried as a native app?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

3 mobile app categories exist in my understanding

1. Native app - built using java for android and objective-c/swift for ios
2. Hybrid app - built using HTML, CSS, Javascript but wrapped for each platform using Cordova (Phonegap), Iconic, etc...
3. HTML5 app - built entirely using HTML, CSS, Javascript and can be opened in mobile web browsers

I have the following questions:

1. Is a web application converted into an android app using a `Webview` placed in the category of a native app? Please clarify.
2. When you build an HTML5 app (category 3 above), you write code in HTML, CSS and Javascript but do you use a `Webview` or do you just access the HTML pages using a mobile browser?
3. Can a hybrid app be opened in a web browser in addition to accessing it as a native app?
4. Can one upload an HTML5 app to the app store? I understand it needs no approval. Can it even be priced?
5. What kind of apps are predominantly developed in companies?
6. Should the HTML, CSS code be made responsive before it can be used in Cordova? If no, can Bootstrap be used before using it in Cordova?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is a web application converted into an android app using a `Webview` placed in the category of a native app? Please clarify.

This is probably more in the second category - you download the app from the app store and it exists as a real app on your phone, but it just displays a webpage. It's similar to Phonegap or Cordova, but less evolved.

> 2. When you build an HTML5 app (category 3 above), you write code in HTML, CSS and Javascript but do you use a `Webview` or do you just access the HTML pages using a mobile browser?

You just access it normally in a web browser, and it's coded exactly like you would code your desktop website.

> 3. Can a hybrid app be opened in a web browser in addition to accessing it as a native app?

No, a hybrid app is really an app - you must launch it on your phone like you would launch any other app.

> 4. Can one upload an HTML5 app to the app store? I understand it needs no approval. Can it even be priced?

If by HTML5 app you mean something not made with Cordova or contained in a `Webview`, then no, it can't be submitted to the app store, since it's only a website. If it is wrapped in Cordova or even in a simple `Webview`, it can be uploaded normally to the app store and even be priced, as it's an app like any other one.

> 5. What kind of apps are predominantly developed in companies?

Most companies want to build native apps since the look and feel is much better. Some companies will settle for the second category because it's cheaper, and some other, like a local business, will just make sure their website looks good on mobile (third category) since an app would be overkill.

> 6. Should the HTML, CSS code be made responsive before it can be used in Cordova? If no, can Bootstrap be used before using it in Cordova?

If you want to use the same code in Cordova, you should design your HTML and CSS to be responsive - making a website responsive later takes longer and is harder than just coding mobile-first from the start. `bootstrap`, like you mentioned, is a good starting point.